# Azure app service: the web server failed to respond within the specified time

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have hosted .net core base custom Rest API and hosted at Azure. This is working fine at Local but getting request timeout error after hosting

500 - The request timed out.
The web server failed to respond within the specified time.

Please help

Comment: Where did you host your API? Azure App Service? VM or somewhere else?

Comment: It sounds like there's a bug in the code that it's in an endless loop or hung.  The thing to do is to figure out what the code is doing when you make a request.  A dump is helpful in these cases.